# how to handle 2D array in case of dynamic memory, i.e., number of elements are undefined at compilation time

Tags: c, arrays, memory

Need to handle A[i][j], where i and j are user defined
In case of 2D normal
`a[4][5]` , this will create matrix of 4X5, and so 20 contiguous memory will be allocated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us, describing your problems with it.

Comment: In what context? Aside: your pre-defined array has `4 * 5 = 20` contiguous elements, not `4 + 5 = 9`.

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate a pointer to the [4][5] matrix. This will also initialize all the elements to zero.

```
   int (*a)[4][5] = calloc(1, sizeof(*a)) ;
   // Set, or get
   *a[i][j] = 5 ;
   printf("%d\n", *a[i][j]) ;
   // When done with a.
   free(a) ;
```

Note that the referencing elements as *a[i][j] is needed only when the array is declared. If the array is passed to a different function (e.g., `calc(a)`) possible to reference the elements without the indirection

```
void calc(int a[4][5])
{
  // Use just a
  a[2][3] = 5 ;
  printf("%d", a[2][3]) ;
}

void f1()
{
   int (*a)[4][5] = calloc(1, sizeof(*a)) ;
   // Need to refer to *a
   *a[3][4] = 5 ;
   printf("%d", *a[2][3]) ;
   calc(a) ;
}
```

Comment: @ryyker See additional comments about referencing elements via a/*a

Comment: My bad, deleting comment and up clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate it at run-time.

```
int x = 4; /* Or whatever number you have */
int y = 5; /* Or whatever number you have */
int * matrix = ( int * )malloc( x * y * sizeof( int ) );
```

Comment: No need (and not desirable) to cast output of `malloc, calloc` or `realloc` in `C`.  (in `C++` there is a need to cast.)   int *matrix = malloc( x * y * sizeof( *matrix) );` is sufficient.